# Need help identifying a sound

Tags: birds, california, night

I wondered if anybody could help me identify the animal producing the sound that I just about managed to [record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o4k_1SfAuxX3IhtvcT1846r_YGlBMZCn/view?usp=sharing) with my phone (it was extremely quiet, so I apologize for the low quality of the recording). Said animal (presumably a bird, but maybe a feline?) appeared to be communicating with an owl which can also be heard.

We heard this sound in Cleveland National Forest on top of mt Laguna near San Diego, California. The time was around 23:00 in mid-December.

Comment: You could try https://www.xeno-canto.org/ , which has recordings of bird sounds. To my untrained ear it sounds like an owl, so I would look up what owl species are in that area, and then listen to recordings of those species to see if that sounds like what you heard.

Comment: Do you mean both animals sound like owls? They seem extremely different to me.

Comment: The first sound is very likely an owl.  The second is most likely not.  Nor does it sound like a cat.

Comment: It is the second sound that this question is about. The owl has a pretty characteristic sound that seems easily identifiable to me.

Comment: It is in the very least reassuring to know that this was not a cat, as we were concerned that it might have been a mountain lion in close proximity. :)

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/merlin-bird-id-by-cornell-lab/id773457673